# How to get product name by id from commerce order?

Tags: commerce

How to get product name by id? I want send mail with product name to customer after confirm commerce order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A product is an entity, so you can use [`entity_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_load/7).

```
$product = entity_load('commerce_product', $product_id);
$title = $product->title;
```

Commerce provides its own shortcut, though:

```
$product = commerce_product_load($product_id);
$title = $product->title;
```

Answer (score 3):

The `entity_load()` is deprecated since 8.0.0. For Drupal 9 use:

```
// Several product ids to load.
$product_id_to_load = [34, 342, 567];

if (count($product_id_to_load) > 0) {
    $entity_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
    $products = $entity_manager->getStorage('commerce_product')->loadMultiple($product_id_to_load);
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $titles[$product->product_id->value] = $product->get('title')->value;
    }
}
```